# TreeView Component Editor

Tags: delphi, treeview, editor, components, delphi-7

if we derrived a component from TDbGrid, we can use ShowCollectionEditor in ExecuteVerb method for invoke its component editor,
so, what is component editor for TTreeView?
i mean when we right click on TreeView, we can see "Item Editor.."
how can we invoke that?

i try to use this:

```
procedure TComponentExMenu.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: ShowMessage('SomeThing..');
    1:
      if Component is TMyDBGrid then
        ShowCollectionEditor(Designer, Component, TMyDBGrid(Component).Columns, 'Columns')
      else if Component is TMyTreeView then
        inherited ExecuteVerb(0)
  end;
end;
```

but not works.

my component is derrived from CustomTreeView.
i use delphi 7.

thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, right-clicking in the IDE, during design-time ?

That editor and similar things (or at least APi for them) you can find in

- c:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\Property Editors\
- c:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\ToolsAPI\

They are part of c:\RAD Studio\9.0\lib\win32\release\designide.dcp

For what i understand, they are considered part of Delphi IDE itself and redistribution of them would constitute an act of piracy. Also there is not warranty that package would work correctly without IDE running.

---

If you need to embed that into your programs, try opensource `Virtual TreeView`.
There are demos that would make is somewhat easier to you to write such an editor. 
And if you'd manage to detach its design-time editor from IDE services, you would have all the needed redistribution rights.

Comment: not even in TreeIntf.pas ? Well, you ca ntry to adapt the code from ClxNodeEdit.pas - but that still be a license violation. You'd better to find a 3rd-party code rather than trying to pirate Delphi. Maybe from VTV, or maybe from CodeTyphon, or whatever

Comment: i saw VTV but there was for header editing wizard..
maybe i should write one, i saw even that unit, maybe it was there but i could not underestand how can i use ..
it wasnot any procedure compatible to invoke from component editor methos